# Можно-ли опустить сервер посылая много post - запросов?

Tags: php, сервер, post, get

У меня есть переменная `$_POST['var']`, которую мы получаем с формы.
Используем ее только для вывода с нее данных на экран.
Можно ли перезагрузить / выключить сервер, посылая огромное кол-во запросов?

Comment: @BOPOH, связана. "Опустить" в смысли "положить", "повесить". И "перегрузить" в нём же, только более мягкий вариант.

Comment: Но это не мешает вопросу быть отвратно сформулированным. Что значит "только для вывода с нее данных на экран"? И желательно какой-нибудь код этого вывода.

Answer (score 4):

Перегрузить нормально настроенный сервер в шататном режиме простым запросом нельзя, НТТР-сервер имеет ограничение, и в ответ на слишком длинный запрос сгенерирует ошибку 413.

Перегрузить можно бОльшим количеством запросов в один момент времени, чем это может выдержать сервер.

Или в том случае, когда запрос запускает какой-то "недокументированный" процесс (т.е. на сервере присутствуют вирусы или открыта уязвимость).